# C++ / CLI - Change all files to UNMANAGED by default

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, c++-cli

Does anyone know how to change the default behavior of the /clr switch to make all files unmanaged by default? The default behavior of the switch is to make all files managed. I know I can mark each .cpp file individually, but there are ALOT of them...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ended up leaving the switch OFF in the project properties and then tried turning it on only for those .cpp files that needed it, this worked once I fixed the incompatible options like /RTC1 and /Gm, etc.

*EDIT* In solution explorer, you can right click on the .cpp file and set properties for it, and these will be separate from your project settings.

Comment: Yes, this won't work because the project file needs to know that /clr is enabled for any clr magic to happen.

Comment: Err yes actually this technique works just fine. You can turn /clr on a single file and the result will be a (mostly unmanaged) .net assembly

Comment: Late to the party, I know, but could you add information on how you did this? Where can I find options to switch /clr on for certain files?

Comment: @Jens For each file in you project if you right click it and select properties you can configure the file with separate settings from your main project settings. Or select the file and press F4. Hope it works for you, that was from memory so hopefully it's not too foggy... :)

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, no there is no way of, by default, setting each .cpp file to native inside of VS or on the command line. You'll have to do it manually in the IDE (or script something that modifies the proj file).